# How to extract lines that start with either this string or that string?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Newbie UNIX user question ...

The input file (`location.txt`) is this:

```
WGS_LAT deg 12
WGS_LAT min 30
WGS_LAT sec 05
WGS_LAT hsec    29
WGS_LAT northSouth  North
WGS_DLAT    decimalDegreesLatitude  12.501469
WGS_LONG    deg 07
WGS_LONG    min 00
WGS_LONG    sec 05
WGS_LONG    hsec    61
WGS_LONG    eastWest    West
WGS_DLONG   decimalDegreesLongitude -70.015606
```

I want to get all lines that start with `WGS_LAT` or `WGS_DLAT`.

First, is `grep` the tool you recommend for this job?

Second, if it is, then how to express the pattern? All of these failed:

```
grep ^WGS_LAT|^WGS_DLAT location.txt
grep ^(WGS_LAT|WGS_DLAT) location.txt
grep ^WGS_D?LAT location.txt
```

What is the correct pattern, please?

Comment: Does `grep "^WGS_LAT\|^WGS_DLAT" location.txt` solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should always quote your regular expressions to protect them from the shell. For example, `|` has special meaning in the shell, it is the pipe operator that allows you to pass the output of one program as input to another. So the unquoted `grep ^WGS_LAT|^WGS_DLAT location.txt` is interpreted as "run `grep ^WGS_LAT` and pass its output as input to `^WGS_DLAT location.txt`.

Next, `grep` uses [Basic Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/BRE-vs-ERE.html) by default, and to get the `|` to mean OR you need to either escape it as `\|` or use the `-E` (or `-P` flag if you are using GNU `grep`, which enables PCRE) to enable extended regular expressions. So all of these should work for you:

```
grep -E '^WGS_LAT|^WGS_DLAT' location.txt
grep -E '^(WGS_LAT|WGS_DLAT)' location.txt
grep '^WGS_LAT\|^WGS_DLAT' location.txt
```

Or, more simply, grep for lines starting with `WGS_` and an optional `D` followed by `LAT`:

```
grep -E '^WGS_D?LAT' location.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Grep can handle two types of regular expressions:

- Basic regular expressions (BRE) which you call using `grep PATTERN file`
- Extended regular expressions (ERE) which you call using `grep -E PATTERN file`

So by default grep makes use of BRE.

When reading the man-pages of `grep` you find

> **Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions**
> In basic regular expressions the meta-characters `?`, `+`, `{`, `|`, `(`, and `)` lose their
> special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions `\?`, `\+`, `\{`,  `\|`,  `\(`,  and `\)`.

So, in your case the answer is:

```
$ grep "^\(WGS_LAT\|WGS_DLAT \)" location.txt
$ grep -E "^(WGS_LAT|WGS_DLAT)" location.txt
$ grep "^WGS_D\?LAT" location.txt
$ grep -E "^WGS_D?LAT" location.txt
```

Comment: Some grep implementations, including GNU `grep`, the default on Linux systems, can also handle PCREs with `-P`.